# writing an interpreter

Tags: analyzer, lexical

I was going to write a lexical analyzer for Java in Python. Is this even a possibility? Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: All I know is: loooot of pattern matching. ;)

Comment: Blackbear is right, I wrote one using C and it was errr.. fun :)